# Write text in random location

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to javascript and I am trying to create an interface where multiple users input a string of text into a form, and after submitting, the text appears randomly on the page along with the previous users input. Is there a way to do this with javascript? I am mostly having issues with finding a way to write text to a specific location on the screen.

Comment: `<div style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;left:30px;top:100px;"><!-- content --></div>` would allow you to place the content almost anywhere on the screen. (changing `left` and `top` of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you create a new element each time, and set the following CSS on it so as to be able to position it manually:

```
position: absolute;
left: _px;
top: _px;
```

where `_` can be generated through `Math.random()`. This function returns a decimal value between 0 and 1, so stretch and round it appropriately to get random integer pixel coordinates on the screen: http://jsfiddle.net/6eTcD/2/.

```
​document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var text = this.querySelector("input[type='text']").value;

    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.textContent = text;
    elem.style.position = "absolute";
    elem.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth) + "px";
    elem.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight) + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
});
```

Comment: This is helpful however the text is being placed in the same spot every time. How would I change it so that the text is placed randomly all over the window?

Comment: @user1819062: What browser are you using? It works as you expect on Chrome.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I was using Firefox and it wasn't showing properly.

One last question, if I wanted to have a random font size generated each time (within a limit) how would I approach that?

Comment: @user1819062: The same technique, i.e. `elem.style.fontSize = (Math.round(Math.random() * 30) + 10) + "pt";` for sizes 10-40. Keep in mind that `left`/`top` are the top left coordinates of the element, so with a big font size the elements can more easily appear  off the page (because the element itself is quite large).

Comment: Thank you. One last question (I promise), when placing my input box inside a div that is centered on the page, the code seems to break. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @user1819062: How does it break and how do you center it?

Comment: Nevermind, error on my part. Everything is working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One final final question. The window gets larger and larger, is there a way to constrain it so that it only prints within the visible window?

Comment: @user1819062: If the window grows then on submit, it uses the new sizes since they are fetched on submit. And a bigger window doesn't add constraints, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a div with absoloute positioning like this:

in your html code: 
    
         my text

In you CSS
    #mydiv {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        width:200px;
    }

You can position your div with jquery

```
$('div.example').css('top', 100);
```

References:

1. [Div Style](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)
2. [jQuery change style](http://api.jquery.com/css/)